# 50s/60s YA science fiction - lost Mongol tribe in Himalayas with American secret agent equipped with technically advanced armor

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

A book for young people (would be classed as YA today, I think) about a lost tribe of Ghengis Khan's Mongols in the Himalayas.

A young American agent (CIA maybe?) is sent to contact the tribe because they are vital in some way (that I don't remember) in the Cold War. There is a Communist agent (Chinese probably but maybe Russian) there too.

The thing I remember that made it sort of science fiction is that the agent was equipped with Mongolian armor and weapons that were made with super advanced materials so he had an advantage over the lost tribesmen.

The book was likely published in the 1950s or early 1960s.

Comment: Crosspost at http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Science_Fiction/YA_science_fiction_lost_Mongol_tribe_in_Himalayas_with_American_secret_agent_equ/abesleuthcom/40037.1?redirCnt=1&dbg=6&nav=messages&mobile=y